# Unix - Using ls with grep

Tags: unix

How can I use ls (or other commands) and grep together to search from specific files for a certain word inside that file?

Example I have a file - 201503003_315_file.txt and I have other files in my dir.
I only want to search files that have a file name that contains *_315_* and inside that file, search for the word "SAMPLE".

Hope this is clear and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can do:</s>

```
ls * _315_* | xargs grep "SAMPLE"
```

The first part: `ls * _315_*` will list only files that have *315* as part of the file name, this list of files is piped to grep which will scan each one of them and look for "SAMPLE"

**UPDATE**

A bit easier (and actually safer) approach was mentioned by David in the comments bellow:

```
grep "SAMPLE" *_315_*.txt
```

The reason why it's safer is that `ls` doesn't handle well special characters.

Another option, as mentioned by Charles Duffy in the comments below:

```
printf '%s\0' *_315_* | xargs -0 grep
```

Comment: No, it won't --- it'll scan the file*names* only.

Comment: Try `grep "SAMPLE" *_315_*.txt`.

Comment: Forgot the xargs - fixed!

Comment: Thanks for you response but this did not work. If I use this separately it works but together, it not returning anything.

Comment: @rgb are you looking in the same directory? in order to help you debug, you'll have to provide more info. But rest assure that both examples do *work* :)

Comment: grep "SAMPLE" *_315_*.txt worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `ls | xargs grep` is dangerous for the reasons given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- safer to use `printf '%s\0' *_315_* | xargs -0 grep`, if one must use such a tool.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, I wrote that piping `ls` output is less preferred approach, I read that it doesn't deal with special characters but I have to admit that I never ran into such a case yet :)

Comment: A corner case doesn't need to be common to be important. I've seen TB of backups deleted by a script that didn't quote when a program creating filenames in the directory it was responsible for had a buffer overflow throwing random junk into filenames (and that random junk included a whitespace-surrounded asterisk).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sounds like best practices about safety weren't applied to that script other than piping ls. Of course that when you're using irreversible commands one should be careful...

Comment: Yup. But how is someone supposed to be expected to be careful when it matters if they don't make a habit of being careful when it doesn't matter too? (With my security hat on -- which I _do_ wear professionally -- I'd also argue that mistaking "cases where it matters" and "cases when it doesn't matter" are the cause of a great many serious problems).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I disagree here: using your approach I will never be able to run in the park because it's dangerous to run crossing the street... ;) I prefer to be aware of the corner cases - and when I deal with something critical - to give it the relevant thought. That said, I do agree that when best practices are not difficult to adopt - it should be adopted at all times

Comment: @alfasin: You shouldn't run _with your eyes closed_ in either the park *or* the street, despite it being the street that's most dangerous. That's the thing -- there's a right way to do these things, and following that right way works in all circumstances. Why, then, do it the wrong way ever?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was still editing my previous comment, please read through :) See updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

Change to that directory (using `cd dir`) and try:

```
grep SAMPLE *_315_*
```

If you really MUST use `ls` AND `grep` try this:

```
ls *_315_* | xargs grep SAMPLE
```

The first example, however, requires less typing...

Comment: No copy. Just needed some time to format my first post. And yes, you are welcome too at stackoverflow, gold-badger.

Comment: @alfasin: 
Mabe you should read this again: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice
Paying special attention to: Don't be a jerk!

Comment: You copied my answer almost line by line and now you're calling me a jerk? you got awareness issues buddy...